# Avoid URI validation for http call in java

Tags: java, spring, url, uri

I have http call where query parameter should contain JSON with symbols like `{` `}` `[` `]` **not** encoded.

Url example:

`http://server.com?queryParam={%22address1%22%3A%2277+tehama%22%2C%}`

in this case `{` `}` should be passed without encoding.

I know that according to *URL Encoding Reference* this symbols should be encoded but it is third party API and it could not be changed in any way.

So far I've tried to make such call with:

- Spring `RestTemplate`
- Spring `org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient`
- Java9 `java.net.http.HttpClient`

All this clients have URI validation and do not allow to make such call. 
Spring clients consider `{*}` as parameter name and fails with exception and java `HttpClient` fails with `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query`.

Is there a way to disable validation for mentioned clients or some other http client (maybe low level) which will allow such kind of calls?

Comment: JSON as a query parameter and URL not encoded.. it's not even an API in my opinion, but you cannot avoid from encoding. If you need to send "{" as first character try to use %7B and %7D to close the bracket.. the receiver of the call will receives it decoded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way to achieve this with `java.net.URL`

Code sample:

```
final URL url = new URL("http://server.com?queryParam={%22address1%22%3A%2277+tehama%22%2C%}");
final HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

final Response response;
try (InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream()) {
   response = objectMapper.readValue(inputStream, Response.class);
} catch (final Exception e) {
   log.error("Error when calling API", e);
}
```